# Примите участие в переводе письма о нормах поведения

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, нормы-поведения

Некоторое время назад появилась новая страница «[Норм поведения](/conduct)» (спасибо всем, кто принимал участие в переводе!) Часть запуска Норм  — отправка участникам сообщества Stack Overflow на русском письма, рассказывающего о Нормах в «двух словах». Письмо будет отправлено всем участникам, которые являются часть только русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков (то есть если у кого–то  есть учетная запись как на Stack Overflow на русском, так и в англоязычном сообществе, то он скорее всего уже получил письмо на английском языке.

Пожалуйста, помогите перевести текст письма на русский язык!

#### Письмо

[Снимок письма](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7T4T.png)

> Join us in building a kind, collaborative community
>
> Read Code of Conduct
>
> Our new Code of Conduct came from numerous conversations with the Stack Exchange community. Together, you helped create a code that reinforces our commitment to mutual respect and kindness. Take a moment to read our newly updated Code of Conduct.
>
> Here are some highlights:
>
> - If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Follow our guidelines and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.
> - If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.
> - Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it. Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.
> - Be kind and avoid sarcasm - tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop participating and move on.
> - Flag harmful behavior, whether it’s directed at you or others. It’ll notify moderators or automatically delete the post.
>
> Read the full Code of Conduct
>
> Thanks for helping us be better.

Пожалуйста, внесите правку в общий ответ ниже или оставьте пожелания в виде комментария или дополнительного ответа.

**Обновление**

Итоговая версия письма:

> Присоединяйтесь к формированию сообщества увлеченных и отзывчивых людей, помогающих друг другу.
>
> Прочитать Нормы поведения
>
> Новые нормы поведения являются результатом многочисленных обсуждений среди участников сообщества Stack Exchange. Вместе вы помогли создать нормы, которые укрепляют нашу приверженность к взаимному уважению и доброте. Уделите немного времени, чтобы прочесть обновлённые Нормы поведения.
>
> Несколько положений из них:
>
> - Если Вы пришли в сообщество за помощью, тогда Вам следует предоставить другим участникам всю необходимую информацию, которая имеется в Вашем распоряжении. Это позволит участникам сообщества помочь Вам настолько быстро и эффективно, насколько это возможно. Следуйте рекомендациям и помните, что наше сообщество существует благодаря добровольцам.
> - Если Вы пришли в сообщество чтобы помогать другим - будьте терпеливы и приветливы. Предложите поддержку если видите, что кто-то находится в затруднительном положении или нуждается в помощи.
> - В своих ответах и комментариях старайтесь излагать мысли ясно и конструктивно; когда Вы получаете поддержку в подобном виде - реагируйте адекватно. Правки, комментарии и предложения являются неотъемлемыми атрибутами взаимодействия в нашем сообществе.
> - Будьте благожелательны и избегайте сарказма - интонация не всегда понятна при общении в сети Интернет. В случаях когда беседа становится напряженной, наилучшим решением будет прекратить свое участие в ней.
> - Отмечайте тревогой деструктивное поведение в отношении Вас или других участников сообщества. Это привлечет внимание модераторов или вообще удалит сообщение автоматически.
>
> Прочитать Нормы поведения полностью
>
> Спасибо, что помогаете нам становиться лучше.

Answer (score 6):

> *Join us in building a kind, collaborative community*

Присоединяйтесь к формированию сообщества увлеченных и отзывчивых людей, помогающих друг другу.

> *Read Code of Conduct*

Прочитать Нормы поведения

> *Our new Code of Conduct came from numerous conversations with the Stack Exchange community. Together, you helped create a code that reinforces our commitment to mutual respect and kindness. Take a moment to read our newly updated Code of Conduct.*

Наши новые Нормы поведения являются результатом многочисленных обсуждений среди членов сообщества Stack Exchange. Ваше участие помогло создать нормы, которые укрепляют нашу приверженность ко взаимному уважению и доброте. Уделите немного времени, чтобы прочесть обновлённые Нормы поведения.

> *Here are some highlights*

Вот некоторые положения:

> - *If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Follow our guidelines and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.*

- Если Вы пришли в сообщество за помощью, тогда Вам следует предоставить другим участникам всю необходимую информацию, которая имеется в Вашем распоряжении. Это позволит участникам сообщества помочь Вам настолько быстро и эффективно, насколько это возможно. Следуйте рекомендациям и помните, что наше сообщество существует благодаря добровольцам.

> - *If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.*

- Если Вы пришли в сообщество чтобы помогать другим - будьте терпеливы и приветливы. Предложите поддержку если видите, что кто-то находится в затруднительном положении или нуждается в помощи.

> - *Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it. Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.*

- В своих ответах и комментариях старайтесь излагать мысли ясно и конструктивно; когда Вы получаете поддержку в подобном виде - реагируйте адекватно. Правки, комментарии и предложения являются неотъемлемыми атрибутами взаимодействия в нашем сообществе.

> - *Be kind and avoid sarcasm - tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop participating and move on.*

- Будьте благожелательны и избегайте сарказма - интонация не всегда понятна при общении в сети Интернет. В случаях когда беседа становится напряженной, наилучшим решением будет прекратить свое участие в ней.

> - *Flag harmful behavior, whether it’s directed at you or others. It’ll notify moderators or automatically delete the post.*

- Отмечайте тревогой деструктивное поведение в отношении Вас или других участников сообщества. Это привлечет внимание модераторов или вообще удалит сообщение автоматически.

> *Read the full Code of Conduct*

Прочитать Нормы поведения полностью

> *Thanks for helping us be better.*

Спасибо, что помогаете нам становиться лучше.

**Снимок письма для вдохновения**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: лично меня устраивал и первичный перевод текста, но некоторые фразы в переводе выглядели слишком "сухо" для русскоязычного человека, поэтому я их немного подправил. Но если не нравится правка или не стоило отступать от исходного текста - просто сделайте откат)

Comment: У меня ещё по поводу _"облегчите другим участникам возможность"_ сомнения, т.е. "облегчить ... возможность" как-то не звучит. Моё языковое чутьё почему-то протестует против комбинации этих двух слов (наверное потому, что облегчить можно либо какое-то действие, либо что-то обладающее весом или трудностью - типа ноша, задача), но замена пока не придумывается.

Comment: @i-one, а мне не нравится вот эта формулировка: *Вместе вы помогли создать нормы*. Как-то "режет" ухо и глаз. Может стоит заменить это на нечто такое(как вариант): *Ваше участие помогло создать нормы и т.д.*? Вы, кстати, переводчик?

Comment: @Dima, Вот именно эта фраза переводилась последней, и, по-моему, я её тупо вбил в гугл-переводчик. _"Может стоит заменить это на нечто такое ... ?"_ - да, согласен, хороший вариант. Я не помню какой консенсунс сложился на ru.SO касаемо "вы/Вы" (вроде бы тут даже была тема с обсуждением). Лично я солидарен с [этим](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/) мнением.

Comment: Немного подрихтовал последние пункты и общее форматирование

Comment: @i-one, изменил фразу. По поводу вы/Вы - со школы употребляю "Вы" по отношению к тем, с кем не знаком лично. Так как текст весьма обезличенный и обращен к одной персоне (пользователю), то я решил,что "Вы" - наилучший вариант обращения. По ссылке инфо прочитал, но не согласен. Впрочем, это дело вкуса. Особенно в интернете. Если "Вы" не очень смотрится в тексте - давайте заменим, я вовсе не против)

Comment: *`"Когда оказываете поддержку путем создания ответа или комментария - старайтесь излагать мысли понятно и конструктивно"`* -- жутко тяжеловесно. Может просто -- "В своих ответах и комментариях старайтесь излагать мысли ясно и конструктивно"?

Comment: @avp, Ваш вариант выглядит жизнеспособно, но нужно перефразировать также и вторую часть предложения - после точки с запятой. Может быть так: *В своих ответах и комментариях старайтесь излагать мысли ясно и конструктивно; реагируйте адекватно, когда получаете ответ(-ы) или комментарий(-ии) от участника(-ов) сообщества.*? Или снова громоздко вышло?

Comment: @Dima, мне кажется, что вторая часть в исходном виде вполне нормальна

Comment: @avp, в таком случае - оставим как есть)

Comment: Ребята, большое спасибо за перевод! Пожалуйста, дайте знать, когда по вашему мнению он будет готов. Я сразу передам его коллегам.

Comment: @Dima Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на ваш взгляд можно ли уже загружать перевод в движок?

Comment: @i-one Очень интересно также ваше мнение ^^^

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Очень интересно также ваше мнение ^^^

Comment: @avp Очень интересно также ваше мнение ^^^

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, скорее да, чем нет. Но меня смущает перевод строчки *Read Code of Conduct*. На скриншоте в Вашем вопросе этот текст расположен на интерактивных элементах (или я ошибаюсь?). Т.е. переводить его нужно как инфинитив. Получим вместо *Прочитайте Нормы поведения* - это: *Прочитать Нормы поведения* (например, как на кнопке "Комментировать" рядом с полем комментария). Но я не переводчик и могу ошибаться. Если время терпит - давайте обождем: вдруг кто-нибудь еще посмотрит и поможет с переводом. Если сроки горят, тогда забирайте - на такую мелочь никто внимания не обратит))

Comment: Да, на кнопках лучше будет смотреться "Читать/Прочитать". Ещё я бы предложил: 1) _"отзывчивого сообщества, участники которого помогают друг другу."_ -> _сообщества, участники которого отзывчивы и помогают друг другу._ 2) _"приверженность к взаимному"_ -> _приверженность **ко** взаимному_ 3) _"Следуйте нашим рекомендациям и помните, что наше сообщество существует благодаря добровольцам."_ -> удалить одно из двух слов "нашим/наше" 4) _"Это привлечет внимание модераторов или вообще удалит сообщение автоматически."_ -> удалить слово "вообще"

Comment: @i-one Убирать слово *вообще* нельзя. Т.к. *автоматически* удаляются лишь некоторые сообщения

Comment: Я согласен с идеей инфинитивов. Изначально не посмотрел, что это на кнопках. Также изменил пару оборотов

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, я лишь руководствуюсь близостью к оригиналу (было бы там _at all_ или _completely_), может тогда: _"Это уведомит модераторов или позволит удалить сообщение автоматически."_ ? Да, я бы всё-таки оставил "уведомит", как в оригинале (_notify_). И что насчёт "отзывчивого сообщества", может ли сообщество быть отзывчивым (мне на слух и на глаз как-то не ложится), или всё-таки это свойство его участников?

Comment: @i-one, может так: *Присоединяйтесь к сообществу увлеченных и отзывчивых людей, помогающих друг другу*? (Если что, то "увлеченных" можно убрать, это для эмоциональной окраски).

Comment: @AntonShchyrov последняя правка кривая. Там не инфинитив должен быть.

Comment: @Dima, Я не против, только я бы оставил "формирование" (т.к. в оригинале есть_building_, т.е. смысл в том, что требуется участие, а не просто прийти на готовое), т.е., например: _"Присоединяйтесь к формированию сообщества ..."_.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это текст на кнопке, см. [Снимок письма](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7T4T.png)

Comment: @i-one, ну да. Верно. Проглядел слово "формирование".

Comment: @Suvitruf, по-моему, на скрине кнопки, а на интерактивных элементах необходим максимально обезличенный текст, как мне кажется.

Comment: @i-one ага, упустил момент. Тогда всё норм.

Comment: @Dima ага, хорошо бы скрин в тред вставить картинкой.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, По текущей (12-й) редакции возражений, которые были бы принципиальными, у меня нет.

Comment: @i-one Отлично! Отправлю коллегам в понедельник с утра. Большое спасибо за перевод!

Answer (score 3):

> Join us in building a kind, collaborative community
>
> Read Code of Conduct
>
> Our new Code of Conduct came from numerous conversations with the
>   Stack Exchange community. Together, you helped create a code that
>   reinforces our commitment to mutual respect and kindness. Take a
>   moment to read our newly updated Code of Conduct.
>
> Here are some highlights:
>
> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to
>   help you. Follow our guidelines and remember that our community is
>   made possible by volunteers. If you’re here to help others, be patient
>   and welcoming. Offer support if you see someone struggling or
>   otherwise in need of help. Be clear and constructive when giving
>   feedback, and be open when receiving it. Edits, comments, and
>   suggestions are healthy parts of our community. Be kind and avoid
>   sarcasm - tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it
>   hard to act kindly, stop participating and move on. Flag harmful
>   behavior, whether it’s directed at you or others. It’ll notify
>   moderators or automatically delete the post. Read the full Code of
>   Conduct
>
> Thanks for helping us be better.

Присоединяйтесь к нам для построения сообщества увлеченных и отзывчивых

Прочтите наш Кодекс Поведения

Наш новый Кодекс Поведения родился из многочисленных дискуссий в сообществе StackOverflow. Вы все вместе помогли создать Кодекс, который укрепляет нашу приверженность к взаимному уважению и доброжелательности. Пожалуйста, уделите минуту для того, чтобы прочитать наш обновленный Кодекс.

Основные пункты Кодекса изложены ниже:

Если Вы пришли к нам для получения помощи, сделайте так, чтобы остальным было удобно помогать Вам. Следуйте нашим рекомендациям и помните, что наше сообщество возможно только благодаря помощи добровольцев.

Если Вы пришли сюда для помощи другим, пожалуйста, будьте вежливым и уважительным. Если Вы видите, что кто-то решает проблему или требуется подсказка - предлагайте свою помощь. Предлагая свое решение, пожалуйста, ясно излагайте свою мысль и будьте готовы к ответной реакции.

Редактирование, комментирование и предложения являются частью норм нашего сообщества. Будьте вежливыми, избегайте сарказма, избегайте тональности которая не приветствуется при онлайн общении. Если при общении ситуация начинает переходит грань благожелательности, лучше покинуть дискуссию. Отмечайте специальным флагом дискуссии которые переходят грань благожелательности в отношении Вас или других. Это позволит модераторам сообщества удалить нежелательные дискуссии. Прочтите пожалуйста, полный текст Кодекса Поведения.

Спасибо, за то что помогаете нам стать лучше.

Comment: Ох уж это "Вы" с большой буквы.

Comment: Вы с большой буквы вполне в духе Кодекса - уважение бла-бла... А вы с маленькой буквы - как бы обращение к множеству лиц

Comment: Да я просто думал, что Вы осталось где-то там в 90-х.

Comment: Да-да, еще и Сударь :)

Comment: Не могли бы вы внести ваши предложения в [коллективный перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8134/6)? Я буду использовать именно его как итоговый вариант.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Вы так не могли думать, как минимум потому, что мы с Вами общались не в 90-х, и я всегда писал его с большой буквы ;) Или Вы думаете, что Barmaley остался в 90-х?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не очень понимаю о чем идет речь. Разве опубликовав ответ - я не представил свой вариант?

Comment: @Barmaley Большое спасибо за предложенный вариант! В соседнем ответе ребята коллективно создали перевод. Если это возможно, не могли бы вы внести в него улучшающую правку с вашими предложениями? Я планирую в обозримом будущем добавить коллективный перевод на сайт.