# Является ли нарушением приведение примеров обхода правил "в рамках правил"?

Tags: обсуждение, нормы-поведения

В целом весь вопрос в заголовке. Можно ли искать изъяны в справке, правилах и всевозможных соглашениях на ruSO, Meta ruSO, в том числе в новых "нормах поведения" (англ. Code of conduct) и приводить примеры оных здесь, на Meta?

Если да, то, что за это будет? Если нет, то, как говорится...

**Дополнение**

Ответ желательно подтверждать ссылками на эти самые правила и соглашения. Впрочем, размышления тоже приветствуются.

Пример подобных советов от @Kyubey: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429/199733

Comment: Старое солдатское правило -- `"в самоход ходить можно, попадаться нельзя"`

Comment: Почему "соглашение", а не "кодекс"? И вообще, вроде он сейчас переведён как ["Манифест сообщества"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)?

Comment: [Мяу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/429).

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что разницу между приведёнными вами "словами" с ходу не объясню

Comment: @Kyubey, ну так это можно. И вообще, оно ни капельки не противоречит кодексу.

Comment: Стоп, о какой вообще странице речь? Хоть бы ссылку добавил в вопрос. А то я, кажется, не про ту страницу думал.

Comment: @Qwertiy ни о какой. В целом про порядки на ruSO.

Answer (score 3):

Попробую высказать своё мнение, основанное в первую очередь на наблюдении за темами русскоязычной меты (здесь я последние два года следил практически за каждой темой и читал старые), намного меньше - метаметы.

Stackexchange очень крупная сеть, состоящая из множества сайтов и ещё большего числа участников. Для того, чтобы выработать подходящие правила сети требуется достаточно много слаженной работы большого числа людей, поэтому -- необходим определённый процесс, который стоит соблюдать.

Часть процесса -- сроки, причём достаточно небольшие. Насколько я вижу по анонсам коллег, которые следят за метасайтом -- следующую версию CoC [планируют](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps) обсуждать в период:

> - 7 октября черновик CoC покажут.
> - 10 октября опубликуют релизную версию.

Из сроков прямо вытекает и другой пункт: если вы не знаете английский, то обсуждение на русской мете будет просто неэффективно. Вспоминаю просто саму попытку перевода на русский язык черновика текущего CoC([1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8133/213987), [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7552/213987)): добровольцев было немного, работа затянулась, так что большая часть сроков уже вышла. А ещё ведь надо обдумать, обсудить, а потом ещё и перевести обратно. Это очень долго.

Поэтому идея обсуждения правил сети на русскоязычной части -- попытка с призрачными шансами на воплощение.

Хотите напомню старый анекдот, что нужно искать потерянное не там где светлее, а там где потерял? Здесь что-то подобное. Stackoverflow на русском -- часть огромной сети, но общесетевые правила принято обсуждать даже не на крупнейшем сайте сети (FYI: [это не мы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3793/213987)), а в специально выделенном месте. (Это много где упоминается но всегда мимоходом, как очевидная вещь, вот [например тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4082/213987) фраза "участники сообщества размещают ...  одновременно на русском и *английском сайтах*" -- выделение моё, А К)

Это о том, что касается общесетевой полиси, что у вас упомянуто как "в частности CoC". Боюсь, тут уже поезд во многом ушёл и в обсуждении принять обсуждение вряд ли удастся. Между двумя последними редакциями прошёл достаточно длительный срок -- можно готовиться к участию в следующей, а в этой маловероятно.

Если же брать вопрос в целом, а не конкретно текущие новости про CoC, то в первую очередь рекомендую ознакомиться с этим постом:

- [Как создать вопрос–инициативу?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6835/213987)

(На мете были ещё обсуждения, каким образом нам лучше устроить процесс принятия правил, если интересно -- то вот из [этой темы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6876/213987) вы найдёте достаточно много ссылок на другие темы, да и в самой теме было немало. Я слышал несколько разных точек зрения, каким регламентом нужно в итоге руководствоваться при подготовке инициативы, так что к чему в итоге пришли не знаю, не буду пересказывать, чтобы не ошибиться.)

И во вторую очередь -- вот этим:

- [Your community’s current problems, findings, and initiatives](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8164/213987)

Это была попытка вовлечь интернациональные сообщества в процесс обсуждения и принятия правил, основанная на здравом предположении, что у интернациональных сайтов много одинаковых проблем. Но, к сожалению, особо не применённая. Объективно, не самая простая задача.

Думаю, что большинство моментов станут понятными из этих двух постов, поэтому не буду подробно пересказывать, а может даже и сформулирую то, как я себе вижу подачу качественной обратной связи и новых инициатив:

- на stackoverflow мы придерживаемся конкретных, чётких вопросов по существу, на мете сообщества мы обсуждаем реальные вопросы, касающиеся проблем сообщества, путей улучшения. Тратить время на какие-то гипотетические ситуации, которые никогда не возникнут -- ну, такое. Мне лично в этом плане весьма импонирует прецедентное право: появилась проблема, обсудили, в следующий раз можно не начинать всё заново, а отталкиваться от собранных ранее артефактов.
- проверяйте себя вопросом "какую проблему мы пытаемся решить?"
- придерживайтесь программистского подхода "работает -- не трогай", предлагайте самые минимальные изменения
- придерживайтесь уважительного отношения к собеседникам, предполагайте добрые намерения. помните, что облекая даже самые правильные мысли в неуважительные конструкции -- можно легко оттолкнуть от себя потенциальных сторонников вашей идеи.

И насчёт последней смысловой части вопроса, в том плане "нарушение ли это":

> Является ли нарушением приведение примеров обхода правил “в рамках правил”?

Тут я затрудняюсь с ответом, даже несмотря на то, что являюсь модератором. Причин две: ставить диагнозы по интернету делу неблагодарное. Появится конкретный кейс -- я постараюсь дать с коллегами оперативный ответ, а вот так заочно... вторая причина состоит в том, что я сколько ни перелистываю в уме содержимое нашей меты не могу вспомнить аналогичного вопроса, такая тема просто не обсуждалась ранее.

Не уверен, что смог полностью охватить все поднятые вопросы, возможно будут ещё ответы от других участников.

Answer (score 1):

Искать можно, использовать - нельзя :)

И вообще, практически везде, где есть кодекс поведения, предполагается, что он является не строгими правилами, а некими принципами, на которых строится взаимодействие. Т. е. это не закон, а своеобразный дух закона, которым стоит руководствоваться, а не воспринимать буквально.

Comment: Минусаторы, объясните?

Comment: "Искать можно, использовать - нельзя" — без ссылок, это просто мнение, которое не может быть разрешающим или запрещающим правилом, но там стоит ":)", поэтому не самое страшное. Вот другое же  "Т. е. это не закон, а своеобразный дух закона, которым стоит руководствоваться, а не воспринимать буквально.", может повлечь за собой кучу неприятностей, если кто-то попробует так отнестись к буквальному требованию в одном из таких руководств по поведению в сообществе.

Comment: Вы, как представитель власти, помимо личного мнения олицетворяете собой ещё и толкователя существующих положений по использованию ruSO, поэтому, на мой взгляд, стоит подходить к таким советам более внимательно, ибо они приведут к следствиям в поведении других людей.

Comment: @edem, вот если взять государство, то у него есть конституция. Но одновременно с ней есть уголовный кодекс, административный кодекс и ещё несколько. Что из них более применимо в суде - конституция или соответствующий кодекс? И почему?

Comment: Ну раз вы спрашиваете про судопроизводство, то ответ: последнее, основанное на первом (см. Глава 7. http://constitution.kremlin.ru/)

Comment: @edem, ну т. е. только конституции недостаточно?

Comment: Смотря для чего.